# User With Login becomes User without login when restored to a different instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, authentication

I have a number of SQL Server logins which are configured on Instance A. These SQL Server logins are explicity mapped to specific databases. These databases therefore have the Login name listed as a user in their security container. When I restore the backups from Instance A into Instance B, the database level user becomes a 'user without login'. The user exists at server level in Instance B and it is not a case of the login being orphaned. It literally becomes a 'SQL user without login' rather than a 'SQL user with login'. Does anybody have any ideas as to how to fix this issue? I have exhausted all my options thus far. Nothing seems to work apart from dropping the user at the database level and adding it to the login at server level for that database. However, I am not in a position to keep doing this as it is part of an automated process.

Comment: You need to copy logins from **A** to **B**. It is not enough to create new login on **B** with the same name. See http://tomaslind.net/2014/02/11/copy-logins-sql-server-instances/

Comment: Off-topic for SO - dba is a better fit. Search "orphaned users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not create the logins correctly in Instance B so they have different SIDs than the logins in Instance A.  The database users reference the SID and not the login name so while the login name is the same the database user does not see a login with the SID that it was attached to.

So you need to delete the logins from Instance B that are supposed to be the same as the logins from Instance A.  Then use sp_help_revlogin from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server to copy those logins over to Instance B.

You only need to create the sp_hexadecimal and sp_help_revlogin stored procedures on the instance that you are copying logins from but it doesn't hurt to have it on all of your instances.